# Instruction assigns a value, but the value is not read or used in any subsequent instruction

Tags: java, variables, findbugs

I have a piece of code

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_of_random; i++){

    String str = in.readLine();
    if(str != null){
        String[] randoms = new String[4];
        randoms = str.split(",");

        dateRanges[i] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[0]);
        id[i] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[1]);
        flag[i] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[2]);
        system[i] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[3]);
    }
}
```

When I run this code against findBugs, I get a suggestion for

"String[] randoms = new String[4];"

This instruction assigns a value to a local variable, but the value is not read or used in any subsequent instruction. Often, this indicates an error, because the value computed is never used.

Why do I get this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you initialize a variable to a value (`new String[4]`), and then replace the variable value with another one (the result of `str.split(",")`) just after. The initialization is thus not necessary.

Your code is functionally equivalent to

```
String[] randoms = str.split(",");
```

except it allocates a new String array which is immediately discarded.

Comment: Exactly. Just put `String[] randoms = str.split(",");` in your code and the FindBugs warning is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can simply do this:

```
String[] randoms = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try directly:

```
String[] randoms = str.split(",");
```

You don't need to instanciate a `String[]`, the `split` method already does it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the technique that I call *The I'm dumb technique*.

Typically it is the result of a programmer writing code, but not understanding what they are doing.  At some point the programmer read or heard something like this: "you must initialize all local variables!".  When they wrote the code `String[] randoms` that popped into their head so they added `= new String[4]`.

A more seasoned programmer might look at that and think *I used to be dumb, but not any more!  Lets move the variable declarations out of the loop* and produce something like this:

```
String str;
String[] randoms;
for(int index = 0; index < num_of_random; ++index)
{
    str = in.readLine();
    if (str != null)
    {
        randoms = str.split(",");
        dateRanges[index] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[0]);
        id[index] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[1]);
        flag[index] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[2]);
        system[index] = Integer.parseInt(randoms[3]);
    }
}
```